# Is it necessary or recommended to make a UDP send-only socket async?

Tags: c#, sockets, asyncsocket, system.net.sockets

I am using a UDP socket to send eventlog data to a log analysis server, and don't want to block threads unnecessarily.  The sending application is a Windows background service using a default threadpool.

```
 // Should this be async? It's UDP only...
   public static void LogUDP(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            var hostname = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get<string>("SyslogUDPHostName", string.Empty);
            var portString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get<string>("SyslogUDPHostPort", string.Empty);
            var port = Convert.ToInt32(portString);

            var ipParse = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostname);
            var ip = ipParse.First();

            // Create Endpoint
            var udpEndpoint = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(ip, port);

            // Create Socket
            var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            socket.Ttl = 26;

            // Connect the socket
            socket.Connect(udpEndpoint);

            // Create the encoded buffer
            var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

            // Send the buffer
            var sent = socket.Send(buffer);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Is it necessary or recommended to use Async for UDP based outbound-only messages?

I'm looking through the [sample Microsoft-provided code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example) to learn how to write equivalent Async code, but not sure if it's needed.  My doubt is reaffirmed when I look at the overloads for BeginSend and every method has an AsyncCallback, and in the case of UDP, I'm not sure what to put there (null?)?

Advice welcome.

Comment: If the receive is using Async, then the Send also must use Async.

Comment: @jdweng Why would you say that?

Comment: I've tried with TCP make my receive Async and transmit Sync and always get error message that transmit must use Async.